# Regex to rewrite urls with one or more key/value pairs

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

Can you suggest a regular expression to rewrite the following url:

`http://intranet/myApp/index.cfm/go:welcome.home/fruit:orange/car:ford/age:37/music:rock`

to this:

`http://intranet/myApp/index.cfm?go=welcome.home&fruit=orange&car=ford&age=37&music=rock`

It needs to be able to cater for any number of url parameters of differing definitions.

Currently, I'm only managing to match/replace up to the first url parameter.

```
    <rule>
        <from>/index\.cfm/go:([^:/]*){1}</from>
        <to>/index.cfm?go=$1</to>
    </rule>
```

Not sure if it's possible to add in subsequent replacements for ":" to "=" and "/" to "&" where they exist.

thanks

Comment: From: `/index\.cfm/go:([^:/]*)/fruit:([^:/]*)/car:([^:/]*)/age:([^:/]*)/music:([^:/]*)` To: `/index.cfm?go=$1&fruit=$2&car=$3&age=$4&music=$5`, should work if the parameters is allways in that sequence.

Comment: You can alternatively redirect to a php page that will re-redirect to this page with these variable-value pairs in the `$_GET` query string.

Comment: The best I've been able to do is (\b/(\w*):(\w*)\b)?(\b/(\w*):(\w*)\b)? to be replaced with &$3=$4&$6=$7, which is both messy, finite and adds trailing unwanted characters (which I believe will be ignored).

Comment: Your use of `<rule>` suggests you're not in control of how the transform is done.  What are you feeding that XML to?  *Must* it be a regex solution?

Comment: I'm entering the regex into urlrewrite.xml as part of urlRewriteFilter http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

Comment: Ahh. So this has nothing to do with Perl. You've got a Java web server and you want to transform URLs?

Comment: Since your problem is tricky to do with a regex, if your web server acts like Apache, `http://example.com/index.cfm/foo:bar/` would call `index.cfm` if there's no file called `index.cfm/foo:bar`.  Then `index.cfm` can perform the transform on its own URL.

Answer (score 1):

Can't if you can't include code in "to" beyond interpolation. You could generate a whole bunch of rules that does, though.

```
my $MAX_ARGS = 20;
my ($p, $q);
for (1..$MAX_ARGS) {
    $p .= sprintf('/([^:/]+){%d}:([^/]*){%d}', $_+0, $_+1);
    $q .= sprintf('&$%d=$%d',                  $_+0, $_+1);
    $q =~ s/^&/?/;
    print <<"__EOI__";
    <rule>
        <from>/index\.cfm$p</from>
        <to>/index.cfm?$q</to>
    </rule>
__EOI__
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like parsing HTML, manipulating URIs is better done with a library to handle the many, many edge cases and format complications.  In this case, use the very common [URI library](https://metacpan.org/module/URI) to pull the URI apart and put it back together again.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More;

use URI;

sub path_to_query_string {
    my $uri  = shift;
    my $file = shift;

    # Turn it into a URI object if it isn't already.
    $uri = URI->new($uri) unless eval { $uri->isa("URI"); };

    # Get the path all split up.
    my @path_pairs = $uri->path_segments;

    # Strip everything up to what is the real filename.
    my @path;
    while(@path_pairs) {
        push @path, shift @path_pairs;
        last if $path[-1] eq $file;
    }

    # Put the path bits back.
    $uri->path_segments(@path);

    # Split each key/value pair
    my @pairs;
    for my $pair (@path_pairs) {
        push @pairs, split /:/, $pair;
    }

    # Put them back on the URI
    $uri->query_form(\@pairs);

    return $uri;
}

my %test_urls = (
    "http://intranet/myApp/index.cfm/go:welcome.home/fruit:orange/car:ford/age:37/music:rock" =>
      "http://intranet/myApp/index.cfm?go=welcome.home&fruit=orange&car=ford&age=37&music=rock"
);

for my $have (keys %test_urls) {
    my $want = $test_urls{$have};
    is path_to_query_string($have, "index.cfm"), $want, "path_to_query_string($have)";
}

done_testing;
```